# Json return null

Tags: php, android, json, null, return

I have the next problem doing a json to read in Andorid
(the credentials are hidden but connection going good in others files)

```
class reportes
{
    var $parametro;
    var $conexion;

    function __construct(){
        $host = "IP"; $DBName = "DbName";
        $usuario="user"; $contrasena="pass";

        $driver = "DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};
                   SYSTEM=$host;Uid=$usuario;
                   Pwd=$contrasena;Client_CSet=UTF-8;";
        $this->conexion = odbc_connect($driver, $usuario, $contrasena);
    }


    function consulta($parametro){

    $query=
    "SELECT OHSNME,OHTOT$,OHREPÑ
    FROM MYDB.SANFPRD.FOMHDR
    WHERE OHORDÑ= $parametro ";


    echo $query."<br><br>";

    if ($this->conexion == 0) {echo "Ha fallado la conexion a la BBDD </br>";}
        else{
            $datos = array();
            $result=odbc_exec($this->conexion,$query);
            while($row = odbc_fetch_object($result)){
                $datos[]= $row;
            }
            echo json_encode($datos);
    }

    }//Fin funcion consulta()

}//Fin de la clase

$consultar = new reportes();

$nota_venta = $_REQUEST['parametro'];
$consultar->consulta($nota_venta);
```

the response JSON that i get is:

```
SELECT OHSNME,OHTOT$,OHREPÑ FROM DELLORTO.SANFPRD.FOMHDR WHERE OHORDÑ= 366 

[{"OHSNME":"E.C. GM. ","OHTOT$":"1861.00",null:" A07"}]
```

you can see that OHORDÑ is probably the problem with the 'Ñ'
but this table are part a productive database and i can't update

Comment: Create a view over the table with different column names.  Select from the view.  You can even set the authority on view so whatever your connecting with can't see the other tables only the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution #1, alias the column name to a name without non-ascii characters:

```
$query=
"SELECT OHSNME,OHTOT$,OHREPÑ AS OHREPN
FROM MYDB.SANFPRD.FOMHDR
WHERE OHORDÑ= $parametro ";
```

Solution #2, manually serialize using utf8_encode():

```
        $result=odbc_exec($this->conexion,$query);
        while($row = odbc_fetch_object($result)){
            $_row_fix = array();
            foreach ($row as $field => $val) {
              $_row_fix[utf8_encode($field)] = utf8_encode($val);
            }
            $datos[]= $_row_fix;
        }
```